# How to show/hide mounted drives in Ubuntu dock (left panel) in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: gui, ubuntu-dock

How to show mounted or unmounted drives in Ubuntu LTS 22.04?

[image: ubuntu dock]

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of different solutions suggested mainly based on previous versions, however in LTS 22.04 this is dead simple:

Go to Settings => Apperance => Configure dock behavior

[image: Apperance]

Now toggle the switch next to "Show Volumes and Devices"

[image]